# Calling a non-static method from within static Map Class in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, distributed-caching, static-classes, non-static

[Using DistributedCache in Hadoop by Yavcular](http://yaseminavcular.blogspot.kr/2010/11/using-distributed-cache-in-hadoop.html)

In the above link, it is described how to use DistributedCache in Hadoop in an easy to understand way. But the problem is, when I trt to compile the code, I get the following error:

```
non-static method loadIdUrlMapping(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context) cannot be referenced from a static context
        loadIdUrlMapping(context);
```

What is the workaround? I can not change the Mapper class to non-static, and when I change `loadIdUrlMapping` method signature to static, then I can not access the `idmap` HashSet

Comment: Can you post your version of the code - there is no `cacheItemset` method in the linked article

Comment: sorry, I just changed loadIdUrlMapping(Context context) to cacheItemset(Context context). the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post your version of the code to be sure, but i imagine you have a method called cacheItemset which is defined as static scope:

```
public static void cacheItemset(Context) {
    loadIdUrlMapping(context);
}
```

loadUrlMapping is not defined as a static method, and therefore you are getting a compile error.

If you version of the `ReplacementMapper` class is in it's own class file, then you do not need the static keyword in the class declaration (this is only required if the ReplacementMapper class was an inner-class of another class).

Comment: sorry, I just changed loadIdUrlMapping(Context context) to cacheItemset(Context context). the same thing.

Comment: I have solved the problem myself. The thing was that instead of placing the method inside the static map class, I wrongly places inside the main public class. Moved the method, problem solved. thanks for your help